# MATLAB- passing a function handle parameter into another function as a handle

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, function-handle, nested-function

Working on an assignment involving Genetic Algorithms (loads of headaches, loads of fun). I need to be able to test differing crossover methods and differing mutation methods, to compare their results (part of the paper I have to write for the course). As such, I want to just pass the function names into the Repopulate method, as function handles.

```
function newpop = Repopulate(population, crossOverMethod, mutationMethod)
  ...
  child = crossOverMethod(parent1, parent2, @mutationMethod);
  ...

function child = crossOverMethod(parent1, parent2, mutationMethod)
  ...
  if (mutateThisChild == true)
    child = mutationMethod(child);
  end
  ...
```

The key point here is like 3, parameter 3: how do I pass mutationMethod down another level? If I use the @ symbol, I get told:

```
"mutationMethod" was previously used as a variable,
 conflicting with its use here as the name of a function or command.
```

If I don't use the @ symbol, then mutationMethod gets called, with no parameters, and is quite unhappy.

While I am aware that yes, I could just rewrite my code to make it work differently, I'm now curious as to how to make it actually *work*.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Actually just dont use the @ symbol, use it when you call the *Repopulate* function instead.
Example:

```
function x = fun1(a,m)
    x = fun2(a,m);
end

function y = fun2(b,n)
    y = n(b);
end
```

which we call as:

```
> fun1([1 2 3], @sum)
6
```

Refer to the documentation for [Passing Function Handle Arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/applications-of-function-handles.html)

---

Note you can check if the argument is a function handle by: `isa(m,'function_handle')`. Therefore you can make your function *Repopulate* more flexible by accepting both a function handle and a function name as a string:

```
function x = fun(a,m)
    if ischar(m)
        f = str2func(m);
    elseif isa(m,'function_handle')
        f = m;
    else
        error('expecting a function')
    end
    x = fun2(a,f);
end
```

which now can be called both ways:

```
fun1([1 2 3], @sum)
fun1([1 2 3], 'sum')
```